# derivative on manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth function and $M$ be a smooth manifold of R^n. Assume that $Df(x)v \neq 0$ for all $v$ being tangent to $M$ at $x$ and for all $x$ in $M$. Can we say that $f$ is locally injective on $M$?

Comment: As a linear map $Df(x)$ is injective if it has empty kernel. What does that mean for $Df(x)v$?

Answer (score 1):

Your statement means in other words that the induced map $Df : T_x \to T_{f(x)}$at on the tangent spaces at each point is injective. Now the local injectivity statement you want is precisely the [Inverse function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem). You can find its proof in any book on multivariable analysis, or differentiable manifolds.